# Node specific template with custom html header

Tags: theming, nodes

From time to time I have pages within the Drupal architecture that I don't want to use the standard page.tpl.php.tpl and html.tpl.php.  I want to create a template for specific nodes that uses a unique one for each.  It cannot have any drupal code in it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This applies to Drupal 7...

### page.tpl.php

Make a copy of `page.tpl.php` from your active theme's directory e.g

```
/sites/all/themes/your_theme/page.tpl.php
```

If the theme does not have `page.tpl.php` file then make a copy of Drupal's default version at

```
/modules/system/page.tpl.php
```

Rename your copied file in your theme folder with one of the following naming convention. Use this format for a node content type (example uses a custom content type called 'news'):

```
page--node--news.tpl.php
```

Or for a specific node use the ID number (example uses node ID of 12):

```
page--node--12.tpl.php
```

### html.tpl.php

The same applies for `html.tpl.php` For a specific content type use:

```
html--node--news.tpl.php
```

For a specific node

```
html--node--12.tpl.php
```

These will take precedence over the generic `html.tpl.php` or `page.tpl.php` if the ID or content type matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [theme_debug](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440) if you are dealing with Drupal 7.33 or newer. That will give you all the information you need in the html source code, for the active templates used in your page and - most importantly - for suggested template files that would allow you to override as you see fit.

And yes, you can have a tpl.php file without any php code in it, be it Drupal specific or not.

Good luck!

Comment: My biggest issue is using a specific html.tpl.php for a specific page.  Can this be done?

Comment: Is coding an option for you?

Comment: for sure.  Im not the greatest at creating my own, but I can certainly manipulate it.  I activated theme_debug, it works, but Im not 100% sure what I'm doing with it.  In the end I needs to create 2-3 nodes that have zero drupal code in it.  All the other pages can have the standard Drupal header code(css, js), but there pages need to be blank through and through.  If you look at source code, nothing appears.

Comment: You are talking about the source code of the served html page? You want this to be empty? Pardon the subsequent questions, I have the feeling your requirement is different that the original question.

Comment: no matter. I think your theme_debug did the trick.  I didnt quite understadn what it was doing at first.  But once I did, i was able to create the correct html header and thus create a blank page.  Now i can do this for each node i create that I want outside the normal drupal pages.  thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, happy it worked for you!